# How to select a specialized function template at runtime

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-specialization

Consider this scenario ([godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vbzcqqrTx)):
I have a text buffer and a function that at runtime tells me its encoding:

```cpp
enum class Enc {UTF8, UTF16LE, UTF16BE, UTF32LE, UTF32BE};
Enc detect_encoding_of(std::string_view buf);
```

Then I have a series of functions that can extract the codepoints from the text buffer, according to the encoding. I have organized them specializing a function template with the `enum` above:

```
template<Enc enc> char32_t extract_next_codepoint(const std::string_view buf, std::size_t& pos);
template<> char32_t extract_next_codepoint<Enc::UTF8>(const std::string_view buf, std::size_t& pos);
template<> char32_t extract_next_codepoint<Enc::UTF16LE>(const std::string_view buf, std::size_t& pos);
```

In order to parse the text buffer I have to select the proper function depending on the detected encoding:

```
const std::string_view buf; // filled at runtime
const Enc buf_enc = detect_encoding_of(buf);
std::size_t pos = 0;
switch( buf_enc )
   {
    case Enc::UTF8:
        // parse using extract_next_codepoint<Enc::UTF8>(buf,pos)
        break;

    case Enc::UTF16LE:
        // parse using extract_next_codepoint<Enc::UTF16LE>(buf,pos)
        break;

    // ...
    }
```

The functions `extract_next_codepoint()` are called a lot of time, that's why I'm avoiding runtime polymorphism for this.
The downside of my current solution is that I have to write and maintain a lot of repeated and almost identical code for each of the supported encoding.
Is there a way to write less and let the compiler give a little help?

Comment: You have not avoided runtime polymorphism. You have *implemented* runtime polymorphism yourself. At any rate, whatever hides in the `parse using extract_next_codepoint<whatever>` comments should simply be a call to a function template.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, he wants to choose encoding for `extract_next_codepoint` only once, not on each call to it. That's what he means but avoiding runtime polymorphism.

Comment: @Qwertiy Writing down a type in angle brackets is not runtime polymorphism in any way, shape or form. The switch statement here does runtime polymorphism. Other possible implementations include function pointers and virtual functions. Function templates are not it.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, I have plenty of ways to make runtime choise per each read.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I'm ok with a runtime check if done once, what I'm trying to avoid is an indirection cost each time I extract a codepoint.

Comment: I see. I was trying to suggest exactly what Qwertiy suggests in solution 2, no idea why it didn't come out clear. Solution 1 would be exactly the kind of runtime polymorphism you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of following solutions:

1. Assign a function to function pointer and then call it. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pffz97E4x

   ```
   char32_t (*next)(const std::string_view buf, std::size_t& pos);

   switch (buf_enc)
   {
       case Enc::UTF8:
           next = extract_next_codepoint<Enc::UTF8>;
           break;

       case Enc::UTF16LE:
           next = extract_next_codepoint<Enc::UTF16LE>;
           break;

      // ...
   }

   while (pos<buf.size())
   {
       const char32_t codepoint = next(buf, pos);
       fmt::print("{} at {} got {}\n", buf, pos, (int)codepoint);
   }
   ```
2. Move your logic to separate template function that calls corresponding function. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nzGnoPnnW

   ```
   template <Enc enc> void handle(const std::string_view &buf)
   {
       for (std::size_t pos = 0; pos < buf.size(); )
       {
           const char32_t codepoint = extract_next_codepoint<enc>(buf, pos);
           fmt::print("{} at {} got {}\n", buf, pos, (int)codepoint);
       }  
   }

   ...

   switch (buf_enc)
   {
       case Enc::UTF8:
           handle<Enc::UTF8>(buf);
           break;

       case Enc::UTF16LE:
           handle<Enc::UTF16LE>(buf);
           break;

      // ...
   }
   ```

For me seems like the second solution will work faster, but I haven't checked it and maybe they have the same speed.

Comment: If you could expand a little the second option, would be a great help!

Comment: @MatG, done for both.

Comment: Creating a `std::variant` and using `std::visit` might allow to write the `switch` only once, and not one by function template [Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4465K7bKs).